# how to solve the gaussian brackets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

could someone please explain how the following expression has been reshaped,particularly the gaussion brackets.

$(-1)^n * n +(-1)^{n-1} * \lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \rceil$ has been reshaped to

$(-1)^n (n-\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor)$

and I dont get the steps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the sign has been extracted,

$$(-1)^n\cdot n + (-1)^{n-1}\left\lceil\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rceil = (-1)^n\left(n - \left\lceil \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rceil\right).\tag{1}$$

Then, the identity

$$\left\lceil \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rceil = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\tag{2}$$

was used to rewrite $(1)$ as

$$(-1)^n\left(n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right).$$

The identity $(2)$ is easily verified by a case distinction:

If $n$ is even, $n = 2k$, we have $\frac{n-1}{2} = k - \frac{1}{2}$, and hence $\left\lceil \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rceil = \left\lceil k-\frac{1}{2}\right\rceil = k = \frac{n}{2} = \left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$.

If $n$ is odd, $n = 2k+1$, we have $\frac{n}{2} = k+\frac{1}{2}$, and hence $\left\lceil\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rceil = \lceil k\rceil = k = \left\lfloor k+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$.